# Can I show a table of one custom variable against another?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a number of custom variables set up in google analytics.  We'd like to show a table of event occurrences broken down by two custom variables, e.g. if variable one can be A, B, or C and variable two can be J, K or L:

```
Events |  A  |  B  |  C  |
-------+-----+-----+-----+
   J   | 345 |  65 |  12 |
   K   | 234 |  43 |   7 |
   L   | 123 |  21 |   4 |
-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

How do I get the information in that format?

Comment: Just so I understand...There are 2 variables here, one whose values can be A, B, or C, and the second who's values can be J, K, or L. Are you looking for total events, or events with a particular category/action/label? The more specificity you give, the more like I'll be able to help.

Comment: events with a particular category/action/label.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you want this on your webpage.

Set up your webpage by following the tutorial here:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/1.0/gdataJavascript.html

Then on the section header of "Retrieve Report Data," use this to filter your results:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I actually meant to display this directly in Google Analytics, but thanks.

Comment: This takes you on the right track. There's no way to do this in Google Analytics's interface. You need to use the API.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics API Query Explorer provides a simple interface for querying the Google Analytics API. So, if you're not looking to build an API tool, you can just setup your query in the Query Explorer, and bookmark the permalink it gives you, to easily extract your data.

So, I'm going to build you a sample query that meets this explanation.

Let's say your two variables are stored in the first and second slot. That means we'll set our dimensions to be the values (not the names) of the first two slots.

The metric you're interested in retrieving sounds like its Total Events (but you could also use unique events).

Then, you want to filter the results to be only those that triggered the particular category/action/label combination you want.

The resulting query looks like this:

> **Dimensions**: ga:customVarValue1,ga:customVarValue2
>
> **Metrics**: ga:totalEvents
>
> **Filter**:ga:eventCategory==CATEGORYVALUE;ga:eventAction==ACTIONVALUE;ga:eventLabel==LABELVALUE

The data returned would look something like this:
[image]

[You can try out and customize this query here.](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html?dimensions=ga%253AcustomVarValue1%252Cga%253AcustomVarValue2&metrics=ga%253AtotalEvents&filters=ga%253AeventCategory%253D%253DCATEGORYVALUE%253Bga%253AeventAction%253D%253DACTIONVALUE%253Bga%253AeventLabel%253D%253DLABELVALUE&start-date=2011-01-21&end-date=2011-02-04&max-results=500)

Comment: Looks good but I can't get past the authentication step.

Comment: The authenticate step in the Query Explorer? Try using a different browser. I know sometimes Safari doesn't work. I've had better success in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I was using Firefox, but I'll give it a go in Chrome.